# FreeSwitch(1.6.20) modules.conf file not found

Tags: centos, freeswitch, mod-python

I installed FreeSwitch 1.6.20 and trying to use mod_python module as described on the FreeSwitch Documentation. During this, I did not find the modules.conf file. So mod_python is not installing. I am using CentOS 7.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **"There is no `modules.conf` file in FreeSWITCH."**

As described in https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Configuring+FreeSWITCH

```
FreeSWITCH™ configuration data is stored in XML format
```

where `modules.conf` is one of the configurations (see name):

```
<configuration name="modules.conf" description="Modules">
...
</configuration>
```

as well as `python.conf` is another configuration in FreeSWITCH:

```
<configuration name="python.conf" description="PYTHON Configuration">
```

But these are just xmls sitting in their files:

```
/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml
/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/python.conf.xml
```

Note `.xml` at the end of filename.

So the answer is:

**You need to look at `/etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml` file to find `modules.conf` configuration.**

Or `/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/` if compiled manually and not installed from packages.